# Cannot link my project when using static SFML libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, sfml, portability

I am trying to build a project in Visual Studio using **static SFML libraries**.

I set all the corresponding linker settings and it works: I can build an executable file that **runs anywhere on my machine**. However, **my friends cannot run it: they do not have *msvcp140.dll***. I do not want to pack extra DLLs with the executable, nor do I want them to install additional run-time libraries on their machines.

So I assume **I need to build the project using the "Multi-threaded \MT" setting** (As opposed to the "Multi-threaded DLL \MD" setting)

**But switching to that option causes several linker errors with the SFML library such as:**

*LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in Program.obj*

I am certain I am using the static SFML libraries and they are linked properly, yet I cannot switch to the \MT setting for full portability. In fact, using the dynamic version of the library allows the \MT setting - which is obviously useless, because now SFML doesn't link statically. **Suggestions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, you just have to use a version of SFML that's using the same runtime (or build it yourself). Otherwise you'll get a mismatch as detected by the linker.

When invoking CMake, just set the variable `SFML_USE_STATIC_STD_LIBS` to `TRUE`, e.g. by running `cmake -DSFML_USE_STATIC_STD_LIBS=TRUE .` in your build directory for SFML. Then just build as usual.

Comment: Thanks! Building the libs through CMake solved the issue.
Although it felt incomplete what I did: I built the library locally, but only got the some of the .lib files that were included in the direct SFML download. And I could not find the "include directory" at all. Is this normal? And is it okay to mix these .lib files with the other ones?

Comment: @JaagupAverin No, you'll get everything in the source download (or repository clone). Just set the CMake variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to your preferred installation location, e.g. `C:/SFML` and then build the install target to get everything the way it is in the download.

Comment: Finally figured out how to properly install the build. That settles it for me now. Thanks for the leads.